# Is there a solution to select the first and the last character of certain regex patterns?

Tags: python, regex, cloud-document-ai

There is a very long text in xml format like:

```xml
><span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_21_0_1_0' title='bbox 409 912 417 927'><</span><span class='ocrx_word' id='word_1_21_0_1_1' title='bbox 416 911 446 925'><forest>...
```

This hocr text is made by google document ai. I want to make a searchable pdf using the hocr file, but when I try to make the pdf, the pdf library I use shows me an error. The library handles the word `<forest>` as corrupted xml element. So I want to replace the word `<forest>` into `&lt;forest&gt;`.

I could find the patterns using a regex: `(?!<(div|span|\/span).*>)(<.*>)`

This expression excludes the `<span>` and `</span>` elements, and only includes the words surrounded between `<` and `>`.
But how can I change only the first and the last character?

Comment: so `<forest>` is a tag, otherwise google ai is wrong

Comment: also the `<` in the first `span` is wrong

Comment: Maybe also [`<(?!/?(?:div|span)\b)([^><]*)>`](https://regex101.com/r/MtXhgz/1) (just a bit modified the yet provided answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following instruction:

```
re.sub(r"(?!<(?:div|span|\/span).*>)<([^<>]*)>", "&lt;\1&gt", my_string)
```

Note that `<` and `>` are excluded from the capturing group.

I've also replaced `.*` with `[^<>]*`, because `.` matches also `<` and `>`.

See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/IwlXhw/1).

Comment: If preferred you could write `(?!<(?:div|\/?span).*>)<([^<>]*)>`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SpaJ3p/1)

Comment: Thanks for your comment on my now-deleted answer showing it was incorrect. Somehow, at some point my brain flipped to thinking that a tag could not proceed the part to be changed to it *must* proceed it. I'm a dummy. I should be grateful that I wasn't showered with downvotes. I'll delete this comment when I figure you've probably seen it. Good answer, btw.